# Does clearing app data have side effects?

Tags: app-data

If I clear my app data in Settings does it delete any information?

Comment: Data is information....

Answer (score 3):

Clearing an app's data will make it lose its data, essentially removing progress in games, etc. It will seem to the app as if you just installed it.

On a side note, the question and its title don't match